# What is the normal battery draw for a 2009 Honda Fit?

Tags: honda, battery

I know that each make and model varied in battery draw, please tell me what the normal is for a 2009 Honda Fit?

Comment: Normal under what conditions? Running? All accessories turned on? Off with nothing turned on?

Answer (score 3):

75 - 100 milliamp

This is standard across most modern cars.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "normal" battery draw. It varies depending on whether the engine is running, what the load on the alternator is, how much electricity the alternator is generating, and what accessories are in use.

More accessories being used creates a larger draw. When the engine is off and no accessories or lights are on, there should be minimal draw on the battery; a few milliamps to allow remote entry, theft prevention, stereo memory, and such features to work properly.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about when the vehicle is off, and nothing being used. I could be wrong but when most people talk about battery draw they are talking about a parasitic load. With the exception of short term overloads if the electrical system is working correctly on an automobile you don't draw any power from the battery when the engine is running.